# Low level Keyboard hook application using SetWindowsHookEx MS-Windows API function

Tags: c++, setwindowshookex, wh-keyboard-ll

I am currently underway to develop an application for hooking. I am using C++ to accomplish that and i am using the functions from the MS-Windows hook library.
My application creates a global hook via a .DLL file and then i can send multiplekeystrokes to all the processes(to their main window). I am using the SetWindowsHookEx MS-Windows API function and the "hook type" is WH_KEYBOARD_LL. Even though it works as expected, in some cases ( for example some games ) it seems that even though i am sending the "fake" keystroke,  the game does not seem to "understand" that keystroke. Has anybody any similar issues or suggestions?Thanks a lot.

Comment: Some games use a more low level way of accessing input devices, such as DirectInput, and will not be susceptable to this approach. Instead, you will have to go deeper down to achieve this, by hooking DirectInput or perhaps creating a fake input device driver.

Comment: Thnks rmhartog...will give it a try